# How to fetch rows between two Unix timestamps

Tags: javascript, sqlite, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

In my SQLite DB I have a `created_date` as millisecond timestamps, e.g. `1646384581034`.

So if there are values in this format `2022-03-03 00:00:00` or `2022-03-03T00:00:00`, how can I fetch rows between e.g. this date and the current date?

```
WHERE
  created_date BETWEEN 
    strftime('%s', '2022-03-03 00:00:00') * 1000
    AND
    Current_timstamp
```

This is my requirement, the syntax may be incorrect.

Comment: Between which dates?

Comment: I mean any dates.One will be current timestamp and other will any date with time in the specified format I mentioned in the question(eg:2022-03-03T00:00:00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a datetime like `2022-03-03 00:00:00` or `2022-03-03T00:00:00` to a unix epoch timestamp like the values in the column `created_date` with the function `strftime()`.

For example something like:

```
WHERE created_date > strftime('%s', '2022-03-03 00:00:00') * 1000
```

or:

```
WHERE created_date BETWEEN 
        strftime('%s', '2022-03-03 00:00:00') * 1000
        AND
        strftime('%s', 'now') * 1000
```

The column `created_date` contains miliseconds and this is why the multiplication by 1000 is needed.

Comment: @Notedyouarewatching 2022-03-03 00:00:00 and 2022-03-03T00:00:00 are the same. This is what I asked in my comment. Which timestamps?

Comment: @Notedyouarewatching see my edited answer. If this is not what you want then edit your question and clarify.

Comment: @Notedyouarewatching yes, this is the code in my answer.

Comment: @Notedyouarewatching see my edited answer.

Comment: @Notedyouarewatching where is WHERE?

Comment: @Notedyouarewatching is there a column `created_date` in your table?

Comment: @Notedyouarewatching questions are not asked in the comments section. Ask a new question where you provide all the related info.

Comment: Starting with SQLite version 3.38.0, there also is the `unixepoch(...)` shorthand for `strftime('%s', ...)`, which directly returns a number (as opposed to `strftime('%s', ...)`).

Comment: @Notedyouarewatching don't update the question with a new requirement. This way you invalidate any answers you got. Ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

IF date is a timestamp, you'll need to do like(the following two dates are examples):

```
SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2014-10-09 00:00:00' AND '2014-10-10 23:59:59'
```

Or you can do, I believe:

```
SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE DATE(created_date) BETWEEN '2014-10-09' AND '2014-10-10'
```

Or, since it is a text field:

```
SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-10-09' AND '2014-10-10'
```

Comment: Its not only date,I need date and time at same time

Comment: There is no DATE_FORMAT() function in SQLite

Comment: There is no "DATE" datatype in SQLite. All date fields are text fields. But it works anyway, as long as the dates are properly formatted (e.g. ISO8601)

Comment: @forpas By "it" I meant "the `BETWEEN` operator used on a TEXT field that contains a properly formatted dates", i.e. without formatting them or converting them to anything else first.

Comment: @Notedyouarewatching You do not have "updated your question", you have asked a completely different question. Don't do that. Your original question is answered, you have accepted a response. Don't move the goal post now and try to pressure people in this thread into helping your with "just one more thing". That's not nice behavior. Ask a new question that focuses on using regular expressions in date ranges. I can't imagine why you would ever need this, but you have all the space in the world for explanations in a separate thread. Remove your addition here and post a complete question.

Comment: Ok fine I will do that My main objective of this time range was to use regexp in some fields.I had done this since My question is blocked.Sorry I will remove this part from the question